# Display an Image as a variable

Tags: javascript, variables, constants

I want to store an image in a variable inside a const object, I tried the code below, but it didn't work. How can I have this image displayed when I call this variable?

```
const jogos2018 = {
            LSB_2018_JOGO_1: {
                    Data: "11/03/2018",
                    Hora: "15:00",
                    Imagem: "<img src='Imagens/oponentes/basquetebol/lsb/bmc.png' />",
                    Oponente: "BMC",
                    Placar: "V, 52-42",
                    Torneio: "LSB",
                    Temporada: "Regular",
                    Local: "Ginásio Miécimo da Silva",
                    Mais: "Mais+"
                }};
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use `const img = jogos2018.LSB_2018_JOGO_1.Imagem`?

Comment: *but it didn't work*... Why? What happened? How you tried to display it?
 There's console errors?

Comment: this tag <img src='Imagens/oponentes/basquetebol/lsb/bmc.png' /> is displayed as a string

Comment: You should show the results you get in the question itself, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want collect the image source in a variable. Here is a solution.

```
const jogos2018 = {
            LSB_2018_JOGO_1: {
                    Data: "11/03/2018",
                    Hora: "15:00",
                    Imagem: "Imagens/oponentes/basquetebol/lsb/bmc.png",
                    Oponente: "BMC",
                    Placar: "V, 52-42",
                    Torneio: "LSB",
                    Temporada: "Regular",
                    Local: "Ginásio Miécimo da Silva",
                    Mais: "Mais+"
                }};

  let imgSrc =   jogos2018.LSB_2018_JOGO_1.Imagem;        
  //console.log(imgSrc);
```